# Failed when sending the encrypted text in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm building an Android Application for Encryption & Decryption using AES in Android studio. The application instead is successfully installed in my Android phone.

Function for encrypting & decrypting is run without a problem. But when I tried to send the encrypted text via SMS it's failed.

I've put permission too for sending SMS in AndroidManifest.xml.

Here is the `MainActivity.java`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import se.simbio.encryption.Encryption;

public final class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "Encryption";
    String hasil="";
    String isiText ;
    TextView cipherText ;
    TextView plainText ;
    private Button send;
    private EditText noTelp;

    public String encrypted;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btEnkrip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEncrypt) ;
        Button btDekrip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDecrypt);
        plainText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtEncrypt);
        cipherText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDecrypt);

        noTelp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNomor);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

        // Algoritma

        btEnkrip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String hasil = "";
                Encryption encryption = Encryption.getDefault("KeyEAAK", "SaltEAAK",new byte[16]);
                isiText = plainText.getText().toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < isiText.length(); i++) {
                    int index = isiText.charAt(i);
                    char s = (char)(index+1) ;
                    hasil = hasil + String.valueOf(s);
                }

                String encrypted = encryption.encryptOrNull(hasil);

                cipherText.setText(encrypted);
                plainText.setText(null);
            }
        });

        btDekrip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String hasil = "";
                Encryption encryption = Encryption.getDefault("KeyEAAK", "SaltEAAK",new byte[16]);
                isiText = cipherText.getText().toString();
                String decrypted = encryption.decryptOrNull(isiText);

                for (int i = 0 ; i < decrypted.length(); i++) {
                    int index = decrypted.charAt(i);
                    char s = (char) (index - 1);
                    hasil = hasil + String.valueOf(s);
                }
                plainText.setText(hasil);
                cipherText.setText(null);

            }
        });
// SMS Send
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String number = noTelp.getText().toString();

                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,encrypted,null,null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Success!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Failed, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you get an error while sending the SMS? Or is the SMS simply empty? Can you send a simple String via SMS, so not an encrypted one, does that work?

Comment: Character encoding comes to mind. not familiar with SMS side of things, but are there characters supported?

Comment: What is your android version? Please give more information about environment and error, it will be faster for everyone that want to help you. Maybe it is related to Runtime Permission for Default SMS app.